# Cannot Import name 'spaces' from gym

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror, openai-gym

Everything was working fine, but suddenly running a python task which imports gym and from gym imports spaces leads to an error(though it was working fine before): 
ImportError: cannot import name 'spaces'

I have tried reinstalling gym but then my tensorflow needs bleach version to be 1.5 while gym requires a upgraded version.
I tried upgrading tensoflow from 1.8.0 to 1.12.0, this again throws an error:
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Comment: I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple reasons for this error message. On Windows 10, this can be due to access permissions to gym-related folder. Make sure your Windows user account is granted access to gym and/or python libraries more broadly.